# Why are some units able to move every turn?

Tags: scrolls

I started playing scrolls recently and I realized some of my units can only moved once after they are summoned, I did try to click on them again but it seems they cannot move after I moved them in the previous turn.

For example, Frostbeard moved in the previous turn and after the idol is destroyed I will like to move him but I cant. Is there a way to tell which units can move every turn? If not then which are the units that can move each turn and which can't?

Comment: Ok, I improved my answer and I've provided a list of possibilities, with links to reference scrolls that could affect your units ability to move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few reasons why you may not be able to move your units.  Consider the following list of possibilities.

- Are you trying to move a structure?  Structures can not move, without the use of a spell that allows for a structure to move.
- Has your opponent cast [Binding Root](http://www.scrollsguide.com/wiki/index.php/Binding_Root), or some other spell on your unit?  These types of spells will either decrease or limit your ability to move your unit.
- Have you enhanced your unit with [Dryadic Power](http://www.scrollsguide.com/wiki/index.php/Dryadic_Power), or some other enhancement that limits your units ability to move?  If so, your unit isn't going anywhere until you remove the enhancement from it.

(Thanks Tacroy for pointing out Dryadic Power)

Comment: It's not just opponents - since he's got a Frostbeard he's probably playing Growth, and Growth has an enchantment called [Dryadic Power](http://scrolls.gamepedia.com/Dryadic_Power) which buffs your creature but makes it unable to move. Since Dryadic Power adds a lot of health to a creature, it would be a good enchantment to play on the 1-health Frostbeard.

Comment: hmmm that might be it. i did buffed my Frostbeard but I cannot be sure is it the Dryadic Power. Thanks